# How do I layout 3 labels to have as much height as they need, then have an UIImage take up the rest of the room?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uilabel, uistoryboard

Here is a layout of my view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B0gt.png

_title, _content, _publisher are UILabels. _image is UIImage. They are all subviews of a view container.

I'm trying to layout the items, so that the 3 UILabels have **as much room as they** need (that is, grow in number of lines / height) with a **fixed font size**. Then I want the _image to **change in height** to take up the rest of the room in the container.

I have tried several methods, all of them failed miserably. How do I constrain this out correctly?

Comment: Use top / bottom margin constrains between them, and when you set a text, use [textField sizeToFit] method.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski thanks for the answer. However, sizeToFit changes the font size to fit the frame. I want a fixed font size.

Answer (score 1):

these are the constraints :
titleLabel leadingspace : 10px, trailingspace : 10px, topspace : 10px
vertical space between titleLabel and publisherLabel : 0px
vertical space between publisherLabel and contentLabel : 5px
vertical space between contentLabel and imageView : 10px
imageView bottm space to bottomLayout : 10px

All three labels and imageView has same leading and trailing edges.